# ¡como pongo una imagen de una carpeta en ireport java?

Tags: java, ireport

Hola amigos me podrían ayudar en un problema que tengo, lo que quiero es obtener una imagen que esta guardada en una carpeta que se encuentra en un servidor fuera del que yo estoy pero al cual tengo acceso una vez que obtengo esta imagen pornerlo en mi reporte con ireport pero, esta imagen esta guardada segun algunos parametros por ejemplo son imagenes que contienen la firma de una persona y sus parametros es decir el nombre la imagen se guarda segun (id,nrofirma) es decir en resumen una vez entra a la carpeta tiene que buscar la imagen por su nombre segun los parametros que se manda...

yo he logrado obtener la ruta de la imagen, tambien la imagen pero no se cual necesito para pasarlo a mi reporte

en este codigo es como paso algunos valores como podran ver pase un imagen qu se encuentra en mi proyecto eso si pasa normal

```
 Map parametro = new HashMap();
        parametro.put("codalmacen", codalmacen);
        parametro.put("codsubalmacen", codsubalmacen);
        parametro.put("tipoguia", tipoguia);
        parametro.put("emiguia", emiguia);
        parametro.put("nroguia", nroguia);
        parametro.put("usuariocrea", dataAsig[0][0]);
        parametro.put("usuarioautoriza", usuarioautoriza);
        parametro.put("usuarioatiende", Logueo.id_personal);
        parametro.put("usuarioasignado", usuariocrea); 
        parametro.put("SUBREPORT_CONNECTION", cnp.getConnection());
        parametro.put("SUBREPORT_CONNECTION_PL", cna.getConnection());
        parametro.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "" + getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("m_reportes/"));
        parametro.put("firma",getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ruta + "FirmasPersonal/"+sfirma+"/" + sfirma+numerodefirma+".png"));
        parametro.put("logo2", getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("m_imagen/logo.gif"));
```

este es el codigo donde obtengo la ruta y la imagen

```
    String snrofirma = "SELECT s_firma, n_firma, tf.id_personal as codigo,"
            + " per.ap_paterno ||' '|| per.ap_materno ||' '||per.pr_nombre ||' '|| case when per.sg_nombre is null then '' else per.sg_nombre end as personal"
            + " , tf.id_estado, te.nom_estado as estado"
            + " FROM tab_personal_firma tf"
            + " left outer join tab_personal per on per.id_personal=tf.id_personal"
            + " left outer join tab_estado te on te.id_tabla='0046' and te.id_estado=tf.id_estado"
            + " left outer join tab_sede ts on ts.id_sede=tf.id_sede_crea"
            + " where tf.id_personal='"+usuariocrea+"'";

       String numerodefirma = "";
       String sfirma = "";


       ResultSet rs15 =cnp1.executeQuery(snrofirma);
       while(rs15.next()){

           sfirma=rs15.getString("s_firma");
           numerodefirma=rs15.getString("n_firma");

       }

          if ( numerodefirma =="") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html> <font size=4><b>El personal no tiene Firma</b></font>", this.getTitle(), JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

        }


       System.out.println(numerodefirma);
       System.out.println(sfirma);

    String conexioncarpeta = "SELECT  path,usuario,clave,servidor  FROM tab_ruta where tipo=5 and estado=0";
    try {
        ResultSet rs = cnp1.executeQuery(conexioncarpeta);
        while (rs.next()) {
            ruta = rs.getString("path");
            smbuser = rs.getString("usuario");
            smbclave = rs.getString("clave");
            servidor = rs.getString("servidor");
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);

    }


        try {
            SmbFunction smb = new SmbFunction();
            smb.login(servidor, smbuser, smbclave);
            String archivo = sfirma + numerodefirma + ".png";
            String pathcargo= ruta + "FirmasPersonal/"+sfirma+"/" + archivo;
            ImageIcon imagenfirma = new ImageIcon(smb.getBufferedImage(pathcargo));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Control_Requerimiento_Atender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo claramente el problema, ¿no sabes como pasarle una imagen al reporte? o ¿ si puedes pasarle la imagen al reporte si esta esta almacenada de forma local en tu server.? saludos.

Comment: si se pasar una imagen que esta en mi proyecto,lo que yo quiero es pasar una imagen que  no esta en mi proyecto ni tampoco servidor si no en otro servidor

Comment: En el ireport debes asignarle el tipo java.awt.Image al objeto que permitirá visualizar la imagen dentro del reporte!

Answer (score 1):

como te puse en el omentario, no entendi correctamente si la imagen no se despliega en tu reporte o esta no se despliega unicamente cuando esta en un servidor remoto, en lo personal hago lo siguiente.

Obtener una referencia a la imagen.

```
private String imagenClose;

imagenClose = contex.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("resources/img/close.jpeg");
```

se pasa la ruta de la imagen al reporte mediante un map que es recibido en el reporte como un parametro.

```
map.addAttribute("imagenClose", imagenClose);
```

y en el reporte se declara el parametro asi.

```
<parameter name="imagenClose" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

y se muestra la imagen de esta forma.

```
    <image onErrorType="Blank">
        <reportElement x="1340" y="0" width="15" height="10" uuid="5008897c-06b8-41fe-a952-bb6c25f79d63"/>
        <imageExpression><![CDATA[($P{imagenClose})]]></imageExpression>
    </image>
```

Comment: entiendo lo hiciste  eso funciona cuando la imagen se encuentra en el proyecto o en la maquina pero mi imagen se encuentra fuera , se encuentra en otro servidos por eso tengo q darle la ruta algo asi "192.168.1.85/imagenesfirma/Nro_sede_personal/codigo_personal+cod_firma.+.png" cuando uso esta ruta no me recone.. creo q es por q esta en otro servidor por eso para traer imagenes de otros ser vidores uso   [SmbFunction smb = new SmbFunction();] coon esto obtendo la ruta y tambie la imagen pero nose como poner esto al reporte... si pongo la ruta nosale,,

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas en tu reporte es lo siguiente

```
<imagen hyperlinkType = "None"> 
   <reportElement x = "370" y = anchura "2" = altura "42" = "17" /> 
   <imageExpression class = "java.lang.String"> <! [CDATA [" http://rutaIP/FirmasPersonal/sfirma/" +  $ {F}archivocafe".gif "]]> </ imageExpression> 
</ image>
```